# Instagram Get Recent Tags

Tags: php, instagram

How do i get all pictures which a certain hashtag. The Get Recent Tags API will return 16 most recent tags and supply you with the next tag id, is it possible to get all the tags instead of just 16 of them in just one API call ? Does it have something to do with the min / max tag id ? Please Help

Answer (score 0):

The instagram API will return up to 32* at a time.

To get all of them you would need make multiple API calls and use the min_id and max_id to iterate through them.

*If you set the &count=X you can get up 32 at a time. Otherwise you get 20.